# Put brackets around value and uncertainty with exponent in tables with siunitx

Tags: tables, siunitx

I have a number with an exponent and an uncertainty that I want to display in an S-column in a table.
When I just put it in, the spacing is terrible, and if I tell the column how much space to reserve for the number, the brackets around the value and the uncertainty disappear, making the expression faulty.

It looks something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[separate-uncertainty]{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{| S | S[table-format=1.2(2)e-1] |}
    {not reserved}  &   {reserved}  \\
    1,72(53)e-3 &   1,72(53)e-3 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: The example above looks like this.]

How can I aovoid this but still have a nicely spaced table?

Comment: Possible Duplicate without answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/147801

Comment: The author of this package has already been informed: https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/244