# siunitx table with separate-uncertainty is too wide

Tags: tables, spacing, siunitx

I'm using a tabular environment with the siunitx type `S` and the package option `separate-uncertainty`, like in the example below.  In the resulting document, the columns are too wide, and the 3rd column is half off the page.  Indeed, pdflatex complains of a `Overfull \hbox (185.16673pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 4--10`.  Apparently, LaTeX is miscalculating the width needed for each column.  How can I make the columns tighter?

Minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[separate-uncertainty]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{SSS}
1.1e19        & -2.6e21       & 7.4e20 \\
9.6e20        & 2.6e21        & 6.0e20 \\
-0.497(17)    & -0.456(25)    & -0.224(41) \\
4.67(16)e22   & 7.23(41)e22   & 2.17(39)e22 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Screenshot from resulting document, which shows the 3rd column cut off:

[image: Wrong spacing]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to tell `siunitx` the format of the numbers you are feeding him. This is what I would do to solve your problem :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[separate-uncertainty]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{
S[table-format=-1.3(3)e2, table-align-exponent = false, table-align-uncertainty = false]
S[table-format=-1.3(3)e2, table-align-exponent = false, table-align-uncertainty = false]
S[table-format=-1.3(3)e2, table-align-exponent = false, table-align-uncertainty = false]
}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{First Column} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Second Column} &
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Third Column} \\
    \midrule
    1.1e19       & -2.6e21       & 7.4e20 \\
    9.6e20       & 2.6e21        & 6.0e20 \\
    -0.497(17)   & -0.456(25)    & -0.224(41) \\
    4.67(16)e22  & 7.23(41)e22   & 2.17(39)e22 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Which results in:

[image]

Note that there is currently a limitation with `siunitx` which remove the brackets around the mantissa when a formatting is applied to a `S` column as stated in [siunitx tabular numbers with separated uncertainty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147801/siunitx-tabular-numbers-with-separated-uncertainty) and [Put brackets around value and uncertainty with exponent in tables with siunitx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170917/put-brackets-around-value-and-uncertainty-with-exponent-in-tables-with-siunitx).