# Don't work together: siunitx, multicolumn and uncertainty?

Tags: tables, errors, siunitx

I want a good-looking table with `siunitx`. I thought I can use the S-table from it to sort the numbers (all decimal points under each other etc.).

Unfortunately, It didn't work properly. I get an this error message:

```
siunitx error: "invalid-number" Invalid numerical input 'e'
```

I can't find the solution, can anybody help me here?

```
 \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[
    locale=DE,
    per-mode=fraction,
    output-decimal-marker={{,}},
    separate-uncertainty=true,
    range-phrase={{ bis }},
]{siunitx}
    \begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{Test}
    \label{tab:test}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|*{6}{S[table-format=-3.0]|}}
        \hline
        & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Offset [\si{\milli\volt}]} & {Mean Offset $\pm$ max. Variance  [\si{\milli\volt}]} \\ \hline \hline
        P1        & -241    & -274    & -272    & -258    & -283   & -266 \pm 20           \\ \hline
        P2        & -94     & -99     & -100    & -114    & -105   & -102 \pm 18           \\ \hline
        P3        & 600     & 593     & 595     & 580     & 590    & 511 \pm 100            \\ \hline
        P4        & 300     & 300     & 300     & 290     & 297    & 301 \pm 50            \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Edit:

The Answer for this question is nearly this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/354925/125143

Unfortunately, the uncertainty for example `\pm 20`is not shown in output pdf. Why?

Comment: `siunitx` will add the scientific notation for4 you; it shouldn't be in the source.  Your example doesn't really reflect your question -- it doesn't use the sinutix column types

Comment: Possible duplicate of [siunitx tabular numbers with separated uncertainty](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147801/siunitx-tabular-numbers-with-separated-uncertainty)

Comment: @ChrisH - It's *not* a duplicate. Instead, it's a case of the OP not realizing that he/she needs to "hide" non-numeric data from the operation of an `S` column type.

Comment: You mention "uncertainty" in the title of your posting, but it doesn't appear to occur in your code. Please either fix the title or provide uncertainty-related code.

Comment: @Mico that may be true but it's hard to tell from the example with `c` column types; the accepted answer is very close to what the OP needs

Comment: @ChrisH - It may well be the case that the OP started with one question in mind (see title) and ended up asking a different question in the body of the posting. For sure, the error message `siunitx error: "invalid-number" Invalid numerical input 'e'` is not related to "uncertainty" -- at least not in the sense used by the `siunitx` package. Instead, it's related to the fact that the OP failed to encase the header in a pair of curly braces. If anything, the posting should be closed not for being a duplicate but for falling in the "unclear what you're asking" categatory.

Comment: I really am sorry. I started the question and ended up with the wring table and I totally forgot the right packages in the MWE. The Answer below from @Mico is exactly what I need.

Comment: `Unknown float option H. \begin{table}[H]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> please read https://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/markusp/teaching/guides/guide-tables.pdf or have a look at [Beautiful table samples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112343/beautiful-table-samples)

```
 \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[
    locale=DE,
    per-mode=fraction,
    output-decimal-marker={{,}},
    separate-uncertainty=true,
    range-phrase={{ bis }},
]{siunitx}
    \begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Test}
    \label{tab:test}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|*{5}{S[table-format=-3.0]|}S[table-format=-3.0,table-figures-uncertainty=3]|}
        \hline
        & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Offset [\si{\milli\volt}]} & {Mean Offset $\pm$ max. Variance  [\si{\milli\volt}]} \\ \hline \hline
        P1 & -241& -274 & -272& -258 & -283   & -266 \pm 20\\ \hline
        P2 & -94 & -99  & -100& -114 & -105   & -102 \pm 18\\ \hline
        P3 & 600 & 593  & 595 & 580  & 590    & 511 \pm 100\\ \hline
        P4 & 300 & 300  & 300 & 290  & 297    & 301 \pm 50\\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**My suggestion:**

(but I am not yet happy with the last column)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  locale=DE,
  per-mode=fraction,
  output-decimal-marker={{,}},
  range-phrase={{ bis }},
]{siunitx}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}

\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{skip=5pt}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Test}
  \label{tab:test}
  \begin{tabular}{%
      @{}
    l
        *{5}{S[table-format=-3.0, tight-spacing=true,table-alignment=right]}
        @{\extracolsep{8pt}}
        S[table-format=-3.0,separate-uncertainty=true,table-figures-uncertainty=3,table-align-uncertainty=true]
        @{}
    }
        \toprule
    & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Offset [\si{\milli\volt}]} & {Mean Offset $\pm$ max. Variance  [\si{\milli\volt}]} \\     
        \cmidrule(r{6pt}){1-1}\cmidrule(l{5pt}){2-6}\cmidrule{7-7}
    P1 & -241& -274 & -272& -258 & -283   & -266 \pm 20\\ 
    P2 & -94 & -99  & -100& -114 & -105   & -102 \pm 18\\ 
    P3 & 600 & 593  & 595 & 580  & 590    & 511 \pm 100\\ 
    P4 & 300 & 300  & 300 & 290  & 297    & 301 \pm 50\\ 
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I will check the links. Those tables are really good-looking!

Comment: well, I hope, that you will suggest solution according to the first link in your answer ... :-) . (+1) for it. one more interesting link: https://wiert.me/2014/04/03/andre-vatter-google-wie-tabellen-eigentlich-aussehen-sollten-%EF%BB%BF/

Comment: @Zarko Nice visualisation! I tried to improve the formatting, but I'n not yet happy with the last column. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @samcarter, difficult to say. The both of us haven't information about table background.  I would describe with some math expression, but which one? Like $\overline{\text{offset}}\pm\max\sigma$ [mV] ?

Comment: Would you mind to explain the code of your beautiful table?  *Especially:*  Why are there "@" symbols? Is this `separate-uncertainty=true` necessary when I set in global siunitx settings?

Comment: @Mike1993 `@{}` makes the rules and the text lie flush against each other, otherwise the rules would be longer (see the pdf in the first link). `@{\extracolsep{8pt}}` adds some space between the columns -- I used it to separate the partial lines underneath the header. And `separate-uncertainty=true` should also work as global option, I guess I moved it there during debugging but never moved it back.

Answer (score 5):

You need to encase the contents of the final header cell in a pair of curly braces.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Test table\strut} % use '\strut' to create a bit more vert. separation
    \begin{tabular}{|l|*{6}{S[table-format=-3.0]|}}
    \hline
    & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Numbers 1 [\si{\milli\volt}]} 
    & {Mean $\pm$ max.\ Variance  [\si{\milli\volt}]} \\ % <-- note the curly braces
    \hline \hline
    P1        & -241    & -274    & -272    & -258    & -283   & -266 \\ \hline
    P2        &  -94    &  -99    & -100    & -114    & -105   & -102 \\ \hline
    P3        &  600    &  593    &  595    & 580     &  590   &  511 \\ \hline
    P4        &  300    &  300    &  300    & 290     &  297   &  301 \\ \hline
    P5        & -730    & -734    & -732    & -778    & -741   & -738 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This es what I need! Thanks you! But I don't understand it exactly. The braces, ok, but I need this part as well: {|l|*{6}{S[table-format=-3.0]|}}. What does this part mean, exactly? With {|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|} it don't work even I use the braces in the column's title.

Comment: Btw, How can I use code in the comments properly?

Comment: @Mike1993 - `l` means "left-aligned" column type. `S` is a column type provided by the `siunitx` package. The option `table-format=-3.0` specifies that LaTeX should set aside enough space for a `-` (minus) sign, 3 digits before the (implied) decimal marker, and 0 digits after the (implied) decimal marker. The `*{6}{S[...]}` part means "repeat the `S[...]` column *six times*.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, the uncertainty isn't shown, when I use it the way I did in the edited MWE. How can I get this right? How do you put the code in comments like you did in the last one?

Comment: @Mike1993 - Just change the column type of the final column from `S[table-format=-3.0]` to `S[table-format=-3.0(3), separate-uncertainty=true]`.