# table doesn't fit on the page

Tags: tables, threeparttable

I made a table but it doesn't fit on the page. An image:

[image]

And the code producing the image is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside
%,draft
]{report}

\usepackage[headheight=18pt,a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm, headsep=18pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
%interprete de idioma castellano
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %relacionado al input
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage[hypcap=false]{caption}
%para que funcionen bien las tildes
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}
\usepackage{csquotes} %"para citar bien"
\emergencystretch=2em
\decimalpoint


\begin{document}

%literalmente, los capitulos se reemplazan en input{capit..}. Modoficaciones particulares pueden realizarse desde aquí o desde el capítulo escrito

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Cálculo de p$Ka$ extendido}\label{table:estimación_pka_extendido}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 & \textbf{} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{RM1}} \\ \hline
 &  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{COSMO}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{SS-COSMO}} \\ \hline
 & p$Ka_{\textrm{exp}}$(298K) & p$Ka_{\textrm{calc}}$ & $\Delta$p$Ka$ & p$Ka_{\textrm{calc}}$ & $\Delta$p$Ka$ \\ \hline
\textbf{Ácidos}&  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
cloroacético & 2.85 & 0.5 & 2.4 & 1.4 & 1.5 \\ \hline
4-clorobutírico & 4.52 & 5.0 & -0.5 & 4.7 & -0.2 \\ \hline
2-cloropentanoico\tnote{b} &  & -2.3 &  & 1.0 & \\ \hline
2-clorobutírico & 2.86 & 0.6 & 2.2 & 0.4 & 2.5 \\ \hline
3-clorobutírico & 4.05 & 3.7 & 0.4 & 3.8 & 0.3 \\ \hline
acetoacético & 3.6 & 3.4 & 0.2 & 2.0 & 1.6 \\ \hline
bromoacético & 2.69 & 1.2 & 1.5 & 1.1 & 1.6 \\ \hline
dicloro-acético & 1.41 & -3.2 & 4.6 & -2.5 & 3.9 \\ \hline
iodoacético & 3.12 & 2.1 & 1.1 & 2.8 & 0.3 \\ \hline
L-valina & 2.29 & -1.9 & 4.2 & 2.6 & -0.3 \\ \hline
L-alanina & 2.34 & -1.6 & 3.9 & 2.3 & 0.0 \\ \hline
trichloroacético & 0.7 & -7.0 & 7.7 & -4.7 & 5.4 \\ \hline
2-chloropropanoico & 2.83 & 0.8 & 2.0 & 0.2 & 2.6 \\ \hline
3-chloropropanoico & 3.98 & 3.4 & 0.6 & 5.2 & -1.3 \\ \hline
3-hidroxipropanoico & 4.51 & 3.8 & 0.8 & 3.5 & 1.0 \\ \hline
acético\tnote{a} & 4.75 & ref & ref & ref & ref \\ \hline
fluoroacético & 2.59 & 1.9 & 0.7 & -0.3 & 2.9 \\ \hline
fórmico & 3.75 & 6.4 & -2.6 & 4.3 & -0.6 \\ \hline
pirúvico & 2.39 & -0.3 & 2.7 & 1.3 & 1.1 \\ \hline
glioxílico & 3.18 & 0.3 & 2.9 & 1.0 & 2.2 \\ \hline
propanoico & 4.86 & 4.9 & -0.1 & 4.5 & 0.3 \\ \hline
butanoico & 4.83 & 5.2 & -0.3 & 4.7 & 0.1 \\ \hline
acrílico & 4.25 & 4.6 & -0.3 & 1.5 & 2.7 \\ \hline
láctico & 3.86 & 3.3 & 0.6 & 5.6 & -1.7 \\ \hline
benzoico & 4.2 & 3.7 & 0.5 & 2.2 & 2.0 \\ \hline
\textbf{MAE} &  &  & 1.8 &  & 1.7 \\ \hline
 &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
\textbf{Alcoholes} &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
glicerol(doble hidrato) & 14.15 & 11.0 & 3.2 & 14.1 & 0.0 \\ \hline
fenol & 9.99 & 1.2 & 8.8 & 5.9 & 4.1 \\ \hline
etilenglicol & 14.8 & 12.4 & 2.4 & 12.9 & 1.9 \\ \hline
2-metil-1propanol\tnote{b} &  & 17.6 &  & 20.3 &  \\ \hline
fenilmetanol & 15.4 & 15.6 & -0.2 & 14.0 & 1.4 \\ \hline
butanol & 16.1 & 16.1 & 0.0 & 15.2 & 0.9 \\ \hline
metanol & 15.5 & 14.7 & 0.8 & 12.5 & 3.0 \\ \hline
trifluoroetanol & 12.47 & 4.6 & 7.8 & 9.8 & 2.7 \\ \hline
etanol\tnote{a} & 15.9 & ref & ref & ref & ref \\ \hline
n-propanol & 16 & 16.2 & -0.2 & 16.4 & -0.4 \\ \hline
terbutanol & 19.2 & 17.3 & 1.9 & 16.3 & 2.9 \\ \hline
\textbf{MAE} &  &  & 2.8 &  & 1.9 \\ \hline
 &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
\textbf{Aminoácidos} &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
L-serina & 2.19 & 1.2 & 1.0 & 0.2 & 2.0 \\ \hline
L-isoleucina & 2.32 & 1.9 & 0.4 & 1.3 & 1.0 \\ \hline
glicina\tnote{a} & 2.35 & ref & ref & ref & ref \\ \hline
L-valina & 2.29 & 1.7 & 0.5 & 2.2 & 0.1 \\ \hline
L-alanina & 2.34 & 2.0 & 0.3 & 1.9 & 0.4 \\ \hline
L-arginina & 1.82 & 1.9 & -0.1 & 1.8 & 0.0 \\ \hline
L-lisina & 2.16 & 4.7 & -2.5 & 3.6 & -1.4 \\ \hline
\textbf{MAE} &  &  & 0.8 &  & 0.8 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[a]{\scriptsize Desprotonación de referencia.}
\item[b] {\scriptsize Sin valor experimental.}
\item {Estimación y comparación de p$Ka$ calculados con RM1 y dos estrategias de solvatación: implícita (COSMO) y explícita-implícita(Solvateshell-COSMO). El $\Delta$p$Ka$ se realizó como $\Delta$p$Ka$=p$Ka_{\textrm{exp}}$-p$Ka_{\textrm{calc}}$. La sigla SS significa Solvateshell.}
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Any help to fix it?I don't want to decrease the width but only the length, if it is possible.

Comment: Please free the data from the data prison: http://betterposters.blogspot.de/2012/08/the-data-prison.html

Comment: @samcarter ooh..but I like. Is there any reason to avoid "prison"(horrible word)?

Comment: actually there are a couple of reasons, the main issue is that all the lines decrease the information-to-ink-ratio. In case you are interested about that, there is a nice book which also deals with things like that: Edward Tufte -- The Visual Display of Quantitative Information.

Comment: @samcarter I am interested to fix this problem first. Then I will look how to transform the table, I think it can be done replacing `\hline` isn't it?

Comment: also have a look at https://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/markusp/teaching/guides/guide-tables.pdf

Comment: To solve the problem: either use `longtable` to split it over multiple pages or from the looks of it the table could actually be split into multiple tables, one for `Alcoholes`, one for `Ácidos` etc.

Comment: hmm you are right. Do you recommend to remove vertical and horizontal lines here or  only vertical? @samcarter

Comment: Most of the horizontal lines too. And try to avoid `adjustbox` in combination with a table, it will mess up the font size.

Comment: Maybe have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/354998/36296

Comment: I have asked it on a question, maybe you can help me@samcarter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see if the following make-up of your table is acceptable:

[image]

in your *mwe* i made the following changes:

- since your table is with `\normalsize` fotn size to tall for one page, i reduced font size to `\footnotesize` if this sizew is to small, than the only options is use `longtable` and split table to two pages
- remove all vertical and the most of horizontal lines.
- for remain horizontal line i used rule from `booktabs` package
- remove empšty rows and istead of them use `\addlinespaces` from `booltabs` package
- for column type i select `S` columns from `siunitx` package

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside
%,draft
]{report}

\usepackage[showframe,
            a4paper,
            headheight=18pt, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm, headsep=18pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
%interprete de idioma castellano
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %relacionado al input
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
%\floatstyle{plaintop}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
%\usepackage[hypcap=false]{caption}
%para que funcionen bien las tildes
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},
            final,tracking=true,kerning=true,
            spacing=true,factor=1100,
            stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}
\usepackage{csquotes} %"para citar bien"
\emergencystretch=2em
\decimalpoint

\usepackage{booktabs}  % added
\usepackage{siunitx}   % added
\usepackage{caption}   % added

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[hp]
\centering
\footnotesize
\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.9}
\captionsetup{skip=1ex}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Cálculo de \textit{pKa} extendido}
    \label{table:estimación_pka_extendido}
\begin{tabular}{ l
            *{5}{S[table-format=2.2]}
               }
    \toprule
    &       & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{RM1}}                  \\
    \cmidrule{2-6}
    &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{COSMO}}
                    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{SS-COSMO}}     \\
    \cmidrule(lr){3-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-6}
    & {$\mathit{pKa}_{\exp}(298$K)}
            & {$\mathit{pKa}_{\textrm{calc}}$}
                    & {$\Delta\mathit{pKa}$}
                            & {$\mathit{pKa}_{\textrm{calc}}$}
                                    & {$\Delta\mathit{pKa}$}    \\
    \midrule
\textbf{Ácidos}
    &       &       &       &       &                           \\
    \midrule
cloroacético
    & 2.85  & 0.5   & 2.4   & 1.4   & 1.5                       \\
4-clorobutírico
    & 4.52  & 5.0   & -0.5  & 4.7   & -0.2                      \\
2-cloropentanoico\tnote{b}
    &       & -2.3  &       & 1.0   &                           \\
2-clorobutírico
    & 2.86  & 0.6   & 2.2   & 0.4   & 2.5                       \\
3-clorobutírico
    & 4.05  & 3.7   & 0.4   & 3.8   & 0.3                       \\
acetoacético
    & 3.6   & 3.4   & 0.2   & 2.0   & 1.6                       \\
bromoacético
    & 2.69  & 1.2   & 1.5   & 1.1   & 1.6                       \\
dicloro-acético
    & 1.41  & -3.2  & 4.6   & -2.5  & 3.9                       \\
iodoacético
    & 3.12  & 2.1   & 1.1   & 2.8   & 0.3                       \\
L-valina
    & 2.29  & -1.9  & 4.2   & 2.6   & -0.3                      \\
L-alanina
    & 2.34  & -1.6  & 3.9   & 2.3   & 0.0                       \\
trichloroacético
    & 0.7   & -7.0  & 7.7   & -4.7  & 5.4                       \\
2-chloropropanoico
    & 2.83  & 0.8   & 2.0   & 0.2   & 2.6                       \\
3-chloropropanoico
    & 3.98  & 3.4   & 0.6   & 5.2   & -1.3                      \\
3-hidroxipropanoico
    & 4.51  & 3.8   & 0.8   & 3.5   & 1.0                       \\
acético\tnote{a}
    & 4.75  & {ref} & {ref} & {ref} & {ref}                     \\
fluoroacético
    & 2.59  & 1.9   & 0.7   & -0.3  & 2.9                       \\
fórmico
    & 3.75  & 6.4   & -2.6  & 4.3   & -0.6                      \\
pirúvico
    & 2.39  & -0.3  & 2.7   & 1.3   & 1.1                       \\
glioxílico
    & 3.18  & 0.3   & 2.9   & 1.0   & 2.2                       \\
propanoico
    & 4.86  & 4.9   & -0.1  & 4.5   & 0.3                       \\
butanoico
    & 4.83  & 5.2   & -0.3  & 4.7   & 0.1                       \\
acrílico
    & 4.25  & 4.6   & -0.3  & 1.5   & 2.7                       \\
láctico
    & 3.86  & 3.3   & 0.6   & 5.6   & -1.7                      \\
benzoico
    & 4.2   & 3.7   & 0.5   & 2.2   & 2.0                       \\
    \midrule
\textbf{MAE}
    &       &       & 1.8   &       & 1.7                       \\
    \addlinespace
\textbf{Alcoholes}
    &       &       &       &       &                           \\
    \midrule
glicerol(doble hidrato)
    & 14.15 & 11.0  & 3.2   & 14.1  & 0.0                       \\
fenol
    & 9.99  & 1.2   & 8.8   & 5.9   & 4.1                       \\
etilenglicol
    & 14.8  & 12.4  & 2.4   & 12.9  & 1.9                       \\
2-metil-1propanol\tnote{b}
    &       & 17.6  &       & 20.3  &                           \\
fenilmetanol
    & 15.4  & 15.6  & -0.2  & 14.0  & 1.4                       \\
butanol
    & 16.1  & 16.1  & 0.0   & 15.2  & 0.9                       \\
metanol
    & 15.5  & 14.7  & 0.8   & 12.5  & 3.0                       \\
trifluoroetanol
    & 12.47 & 4.6   & 7.8   & 9.8   & 2.7                       \\
etanol\tnote{a}
    & 15.9  & {ref} & {ref} & {ref} & {ref}                     \\
n-propanol
    & 16    & 16.2  & -0.2  & 16.4  & -0.4                      \\
terbutanol
    & 19.2  & 17.3  & 1.9   & 16.3  & 2.9                       \\
    \midrule
\textbf{MAE}
    &       &       & 2.8   &       & 1.9                       \\
    \addlinespace
\textbf{Aminoácidos}
    &       &       &       &       &                           \\
    \midrule
L-serina
    & 2.19  & 1.2   & 1.0   & 0.2   & 2.0                       \\
L-isoleucina
    & 2.32  & 1.9   & 0.4   & 1.3   & 1.0                       \\
glicina\tnote{a}
    & 2.35  & {ref} & {ref} & {ref} & {ref}                     \\
L-valina
    & 2.29  & 1.7   & 0.5   & 2.2   & 0.1                       \\
L-alanina
    & 2.34  & 2.0   & 0.3   & 1.9   & 0.4                       \\
L-arginina
    & 1.82  & 1.9   & -0.1  & 1.8   & 0.0                       \\
L-lisina
    & 2.16  & 4.7   & -2.5  & 3.6   & -1.4                      \\
    \midrule
\textbf{MAE}
    &       &       & 0.8   &       & 0.8                       \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}\scriptsize
\item[a]    Desprotonación de referencia.
\item[b]    Sin valor experimental.
\item       Estimación y comparación de p$Ka$ calculados con RM1 y dos estrategias de solvatación: implícita (COSMO) y explícita-implícita(Solvateshell-COSMO). El $\Delta$p$Ka$ se realizó como $\Delta$p$Ka$=p$Ka_{\textrm{exp}}$-p$Ka_{\textrm{calc}}$. La sigla SS significa Solvateshell.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**addendum**:

if you like to have table width the same as is text width you have more options. for example use `tabularx` or `tabular*`. use of `adjustbox` is more or less desperate action of last resort when all other actions fails ...

the simplest way seems to me is use of `tabular*` in this case you need make only small changes to code in above *mwe*:

```
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{%
    @{\hspace{\tabcolsep}\extracolsep{\fill}}% this add extra space between columns 
                                             % that the table width become equal to text width
                     l           
                *{5}{S[table-format=2.2]}
                             }
...

\end{tabular*}
```

all others code is the same. in this case the table is looks like this (showed only top part of table):

[image]

*note*: in real document you should remove `geometry` package option `showframe` (which now, only for test purposes, show page layout

*edit*: in code i now consider [Bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38908/bernard) comment below.

Comment: Unbelievably good. Thanks. I will accept in some minutes.

Comment: Would you post the code?

Comment: @HernanMiraola, of course! sorry, but i had troubles with my hardware (frozen editor :-( ), so part of answer was uploaded before i succeed to complete it ...

Comment: Is there any fast way to generate tables? I have around 15

Comment: And I have a question, how can I control the width without adjust box?

Comment: i'm afraid that for good looking tables it not exist. of course they exist some table generators, but i newer use it. i only saw here on side terrible outputs :-(

Comment: yes you can. for example use `tabularx` and prescribe desired width, for example `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XXXXX}` where `X` type of columns (in your example can be used with implicit some trick) or `tabular*`, where you can add extra column separator. both solution you should use with some care, since table can looks very "empty". I try to add example with `tabular*` to my answer asap.

Comment: I@Zarko: In the O.P.'s code, `pKa`  is a term from chemistry and should be typeset in roman, I think.

Comment: @Bernard, i see this strange formatting of `pKa`, but since i don't know what is this, i left it as i find it in the op code assuming, that it should be as is typed. now i will correct this as you suggest.