# How to create a table with varying columns and rows

Tags: tables

My apologies if this has been asked multiple times in the past. But I'm quite new to LateX and have been trying to write a lab report with it. All had been going well until I was trying to create this kind of table.[image]

On another note, is there any possible way to move the table as I please? (the table keeps floating to where ever seems fit but not where I want it).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please, have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/393233/4427, in particular at the image. `;-)`

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! For the floating problem, you can try to add the option `\begin{table[!htb]`.  You also have the `[H]` (meaning: ‘here and nowhere else’), from the `float` package, but it might yield huge vertical spacing. Other than this, could you post a compilable code?

Comment: note a `tabular` makes the layout you show and will never move anywhere. You may have put it in a `table` environment. The _only_ purpose of a `table` environment is to specify that its content may be moved to help with page breaking.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `siunitx` and, possibly, `booktabs`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs} % beautiful tables

\DeclareSIUnit{\rpm}{rpm}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{
  S[table-format=1.3]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=1.3]
  S[table-format=3.0]
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{3}{c}{$I_L=\SI{0.8}{\ampere}$} &
\multicolumn{3}{c}{$I_L=\SI{1.5}{\ampere}$} \\
\multicolumn{3}{c}{$T=\SI{3.46}{\newton\metre}$, $\omega=\SI{1500}{\rpm}$} &
\multicolumn{3}{c}{$T=\SI{4.35}{\newton\metre}$, $\omega=\SI{1500}{\rpm}$} \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-6}
{$I_A$ (\si{\ampere})} &
{$I_f$ (\si{\ampere})} &
{$P_{\mathrm{in}}$ (\si{\watt})} &
{$I_A$ (\si{\ampere})} &
{$I_f$ (\si{\ampere})} &
{$P_{\mathrm{in}}$ (\si{\watt})} \\
\midrule
1.84  & 0.3  & 378 & 2.2  & 0.38 & 532 \\
1.54  & 0.4  & 380 & 1.9  & 0.45 & 527 \\
1.25  & 0.5  & 375 & 1.65 & 0.55 & 527 \\
1.14  & 0.6  & 384 & 1.57 & 0.65 & 530 \\
1.145 & 0.65 & 384 & 1.63 & 0.75 & 530 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Load $V$-curves test}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Note how the units are specified, in a uniform style which is consistent with BIPM rules for the International System.

[image]

There's generally no need to print headers boldface, they're already prominent enough.

Avoid worksheet-like rules: they're good for presenting data on a computer screen, when one has to work with them. For handouts and print, they're just of a hindrance.

[image]

Comment: +1... Beautiful and nice suggestions. I would just prefer a second set of `\cmidrule`s instead of your `\midrule` that "connects" the two separate measurements (and I just don't like this connection).

Comment: @koleygr It's the separator between header and body. The `\cmidrule` above joins the three subheaders with the respective main headers.

Comment: It is probably a matter of taste. You want to separate the body of the headers with a midrule, and you prefer the cmidrule between headers to "connect them". I would prefer to connect the contents (body) of the tabulars in the same parts of measurements and separate them with that way.